# Getting Original Purchase Version Downloaded By User

Tags: swift, version, receipt-validation

so I am changing my app from paid to free and I want to keep the paid customers with the premium features. A way of doing this was to just check their original purchase version of the app and see if it was a paid version and then just give them the premium features but I can only find the users current version of the app instead of the original purchased version.

I have been reading and maybe this might be related to receipt validation but if there was a way to get the users original purchase version of the app, could someone please help.

This is my code which I use to get their current version, not the original purchase one.

```
let version : String! = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
print(version)
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, indeed, with the receipt validation you should see all the purchases of the user and eventually unlock the feature you want after you validated it.
Check the `ASN.1 Field Type 17`, as the [apple docs specify](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW2)
_In the JSON file, the value of this key is an array containing all in-app purchase receipts based on the in-app purchase transactions present in the input base-64 receipt-data_

Comment: and how would I go implementing this? @A_C

Comment: Honestly this had been problematic also for me. I will share the code in an answer because it too long for a comment. I just hope to do not get downvotes because I'm not 100% sure it's the right process :D

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comments I'm not sure if this is the right process, but for an app I made I check the receipt with the following code:

**For any doubts please refer to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) I followed as well.**

Important also to noticed that Apple discourage to directly validate trough AppStore servers (since the identity cannot be verified and this can lead to man-in-the-middle attacks)

*Use a trusted server to communicate with the App Store. Using your own server lets you design your app to recognize and trust only your server, and lets you ensure that your server connects with the App Store server. It is not possible to build a trusted connection between a user’s device and the App Store directly because you don’t control either end of that connection, and therefore can be susceptible to a man-in-the-middle attack.*

But, if can help you here are the two Apple endpoints for (debug/production).

```
    #if DEBUG
    private let appStoreValidationURL = URL(string: "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")!
    #else
    private let appStoreValidationURL = URL(string: "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")!
    #endif
```

While, regarding the `SharedSecret` of your app that you need to pass along the receipt you can find useful informations [here](https://www.appypie.com/faqs/how-can-i-get-shared-secret-key-for-in-app-purchase).

1. Retrieve the receipt.

```
private func loadReceipt() throws -> Data {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL else {
            throw ReceiptValidationError.noReceiptData
        }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            return data
        } catch {
            print("Error loading receipt data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            throw ReceiptValidationError.noReceiptData
        }
    }
```

2. Then you can read the content as a JSON format with

```
[...]
 // Handle the try. I skipped that to make easier to read 
 let data = try! loadReceipt()
 let base64String = data.base64EncodedString(options: [])

 // Encode data in JSON
 let content: [String : Any] = ["receipt-data" : base64String,
                                       "password" : sharedSecret,
                                       "exclude-old-transactions" : true]
```

3. Send your request Receipt to Apple server for validation.

```
private func validateLastReceipt(_ data: Data) {

        let base64String = data.base64EncodedString(options: [])

        // Encode data in JSON
        let content: [String : Any] = ["receipt-data" : base64String,
                                       "password" : sharedSecret,
                                       "exclude-old-transactions" : false]
        let json = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: content, options: [])

        // build request
        let storeURL = self.appStoreValidationURL

        var request = URLRequest(url: storeURL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = json

        // Make request to app store

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, res, error) in
            guard error == nil, let data = data else {
                self.delegate?.validator(self, didFinishValidateWith: error!)
                return
            }

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try decoder.decode(ReceiptAppStoreResponse.self, from: data)                                
            } catch {
                // Handle error
            }

            }.resume()
    }
```

Here the Decodables struct I built. **There you will find all the informations you need to check what the user bought!**

```
private struct ReceiptAppStoreResponse: Decodable {
    /// Either 0 if the receipt is valid, or one of the error codes listed in Table 2-1.
    ///
    /// For iOS 6 style transaction receipts, the status code reflects the status of the specific transaction’s receipt.
    ///
    /// For iOS 7 style app receipts, the status code is reflects the status of the app receipt as a whole. For example, if you send a valid app receipt that contains an expired subscription, the response is 0 because the receipt as a whole is valid.
    let status: Int?

    /// A JSON representation of the receipt that was sent for verification.
//    let receipt: String?

    /// Only returned for receipts containing auto-renewable subscriptions. For iOS 6 style transaction receipts,
    /// this is the base-64 encoded receipt for the most recent renewal. For iOS 7 style app receipts, this is the latest
    /// base-64 encoded app receipt.
    let latestReceipt: String?

    /// Only returned for receipts containing auto-renewable subscriptions. For iOS 6 style transaction receipts,
    /// this is the JSON representation of the receipt for the most recent renewal. For iOS 7 style app receipts,
    /// the value of this key is an array containing all in-app purchase transactions.
    /// This excludes transactions for a consumable product that have been marked as finished by your app.
    let latestReceiptInfo: [ReceiptInfo]?

    /// Only returned for iOS 6 style transaction receipts, for an auto-renewable subscription.
    /// The JSON representation of the receipt for the expired subscription.
    //    let latestExpiredReceiptInfo: String?

    /// Only returned for iOS 7 style app receipts containing auto-renewable subscriptions.
    /// In the JSON file, the value of this key is an array where each element contains the pending renewal information
    /// for each auto-renewable subscription identified by the Product Identifier.
    /// A pending renewal may refer to a renewal that is scheduled in the future or a renewal that failed
    /// in the past for some reason.
    //    let pendingRenewalInfo: String?

    /// Retry validation for this receipt. Only applicable to status codes 21100-21199
    //    let isRetryable: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
//        case receipt
        case latestReceipt = "latest_receipt"
        case latestReceiptInfo = "latest_receipt_info"
        //        case latestExpiredReceiptInfo = "latest_expired_receipt_info"
        //        case pendingRenewalInfo = "pending_renewal_info"
        //        case isRetryable = "is-retryable"
    }

}

struct ReceiptInfo: Decodable {

    let originalTransactionID: String?
    let productID: String?

    let expiresDateMS: String?

    let originalPurchaseDateMS: String?

    let isTrialPeriod: String?
    let isInIntroOfferPeriod: String?

    let purchaseDateMS: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case originalTransactionID = "original_transaction_id"
        case productID = "product_id"

        case expiresDateMS = "expires_date_ms"

        case originalPurchaseDateMS = "original_purchase_date_ms"

        case isTrialPeriod = "is_trial_period"
        case isInIntroOfferPeriod = "is_in_intro_offer_period"

        case purchaseDateMS = "purchase_date_ms"
    }

    func getExpireDate() -> Date? {
        let nf = NumberFormatter()
        guard let expDateString = self.expiresDateMS, let expDateValue = nf.number(from: expDateString) else {
            return nil
        }

        /// It's expressed as milliseconds since 1970!!!
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: expDateValue.doubleValue / 1000)

        return date

    }
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks so much for this in deep explanation. One quick question. in 2. you said " // Handle the try. I skipped that to make easier to read". What do you mean by this? @A_C

Comment: Theoretically if the throwing function returns (or, better, throws) an error it is handled by the catch part. I skipped that and used the force-try with `try!`, but doing this if the throwing function throws an error the app crashes. Check how I've done in point 1.